# Closed positively invariant subset is a subset of a basin in an autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory, set-invariance

I have a doubt about a theorem in Hirsch and Smale's Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra textbook. In the chapter of Stability of equilibria they state

> **Theorem 2** Let $\bar{x}\in W$ be an equilibrium of the dynamical system $(1)$ and let $V:U\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Liapunov function for $\bar{x}$, $U$ a neighborhood of $\bar{x}$. let $P\subset U$ be a neighborhood of $\bar{x}$ which is closed in $W$. Suppose that $P$ is a positively invariant, and that there is no entire orbit in $P-\bar{x}$ on which $V$ is constant. Then $\bar{x}$ is asymptotically stable, and $P\subseteq B(\bar{x})$.

Before he writes

> \begin{equation}
> x'=f(x)\tag{1}
> \end{equation}
>   Where $f:W\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^1$ map on an open set $W\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

and

> The union of all the solution curves that tend toward $\bar{x}$ (as $t\to \infty$) is called the basin of $\bar{x}$, denoted by $B(\bar{x})$.

Now the beginning of the proof of **Theorem 2** is

> Imagine a trajectory $x(t)$, $0\le t<\infty$, in the positively invariant set $P$. Suppose $x(t)$ does not tend to $\bar{x}$ as $t\to\infty$. Then there must be a point $a\neq \bar{x}$ in $P$ and a sequence $t_n\to \infty$ such that 
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{n\to \infty}x(t_n)=a
> \end{equation}

So my question is: How do they conclude the existence of such a point $a$? The orbit $x(t)$ might tend to infinity as $t\to \infty$. That can be implied if $P$ is compact, but that is not in the hypothesis. The book Lições de Equações Diferenciais Ordinárias by Sotomayor has a similar theorem with $P$ closed only. Incidentally, a copy of Sotomayor's that I borrowed from the Library has the word compact written above $P$.
If $P$ compact is indeed necessary, I would like to see a counterexample.

Comment: I think Ex. 2.4 on p. 68 of [Stability Theory of Dynamical Systems](https://books.google.pl/books?id=wP5dwTS6jg0C&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=bhatia+szego+stability+theory+of+dynamical+systems+p.+68&source=bl&ots=XgpqNh_HkS&sig=dsVGLm2FD7t-6jqTHD1QIcnQtSo&hl=pl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bhatia%20szego%20stability%20theory%20of%20dynamical%20systems%20p.%2068&f=false) by Bhatia and Szegö could serve as a counterexample.